# How can we know whether a WebView page support scale(zoomIn/zoomOut) or not

Tags: android, webview

For now, i basically use WebView#getScale to deal with it:
1. remember initial scale value when page opened;
2. when scale gesture happens, in onScaleEnd method, compare the current scale value with the initial one, to see if they're changed or not. (compared with a very very small number, like 0.00000001);

It can basically works for most web pages, but i just wonder if there's a better/direct way to detect this from Java code in Android application, something like canScale.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you described covers the widest set of cases.

If you wanted to know this up front (before the user tried to pinch) you could look at the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) but that wouldn't cover the case where the page had installed touch handlers which prevent the pinch gesture.

Comment: finally, i found that WebView has canZoomIn, canZoomOut method though deprecated. Anyway, thanks for comment.